# Error while executing ACL command: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

ZK connection issues while updating ACL rules..

```
./bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=xxx.xxx.xx3:2181,xxx.xxx.xx2:2181,xxx.xxx.xx1:2181 --add --allow-principal User:xxxxxxxx --operation Read --topic xxxxxxxxxx
```

```
[2020-05-12 12:29:01,340] DEBUG An exception was thrown while closing send thread for session 0x300528cdbc70015 : Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x300528cdbc70015, likely server has closed socket (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn) 

Error while executing ACL command: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$waitUntilConnected$3(ZooKeeperClient.scala:258)
    at ....
```

The error is happening intermittently and unable to determine the root cause.

Added on 6/4/2020
Running on localhost seems too never timeout..

```
./bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:xxxxxxx --operation Read --topic xxxxxxx
```

However running against the ensemble is what is causing the timeout..

```
./bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=hostxxxx001:2181,hostxxxx002:2181 --add --allow-principal User:xxxxxxx --operation Read --topic xxxxxxx
```